# Advanced online Excel survey

Tags: excel-2010, excel-2007, survey, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-survey-list

i have a survey i want to perform for 3 different companies.
the normal process is to make the 3 different surveys and make the users fill the 3 online surveys.
is it possible to make one survey for the 3 companies?

below is an screen shot of my survey:
as you can see same questions should be applied to each of "ESKADENIA", "GBM", and "Bsynchro".

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use three worksheets within one workbook and write a password protected macro making use of the `xlSheetVeryHidden` option - you can do this from the Project Explorer dropdown in the VBE, or hard-code it.

However, I think you should be careful if you are sending sensitive information - Microsoft applications are notoriously crackable!